# Why does nobody use the positional args made available to Bash completion functions?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

The Bash man page describes parameters that are available to completion shell functions:

> If a shell function is being invoked, the COMP_WORDS and COMP_CWORD variables are also set.

Using these parameters to identify the current word and previous word seems to be a common idiom:

```
cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}
```

But the documentation goes on to say,

> When the function or command is invoked, the first argument is the name of the command whose arguments are being completed, the second argument is the word being completed, and the third argument is the word preceding the word being completed on the current command line.

So the above code could be replaced with,

```
cur=$2
prev=$3
```

I have yet to see any examples of this usage "in the wild". Why is that? Are people just unaware that these parameters are already available, or is there a compelling reason not to rely on them?

I realize that more nuanced completion mechanisms are available in the bash-completion project ([v1](https://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org),
 [v2](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion)), so neither of the preceding examples are ideal for advanced use-cases, but for simple ones, the positional parameters work out of the box, so why does nobody use them?